# Get SharePoint user detail via Azure Chat bot

Tags: c#, sharepoint, botframework, sharepoint-online

I'm developing a chat bot using bot framework form flow to embed in SharePoint online for service ticket creation.

I have used iFrame for to attach it on share point online. Now I need to get the user name & Email ID of the user logged-in the share point site. Since the bot is hosted on Azure and using iFrame the below commands not applicable here

```
activity.ChannelId;
activity.From.Id;
activity.From.Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand that you want to get user' name and email ID from sharepoint online sites.

I suggest try graph API to get your user'data.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,mail,userPrincipalName
```

References are [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get)

For anonymous user or get access without user, you can try use the OAuth client credentials grant flow to get an access token.

1. [Register your app](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/?referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fgraph%2Fdocs%2Fconcepts%2Fauth_v2_service#/appList).
2. List itemConfigure permissions for Microsoft Graph on your
   app.
3. Get administrator consent.
4. Get an access token.
5. Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph.

For more detailed steps on how to register, here is the [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

Comment: But to use Graph, user needs to authenticate and pass the token to get the details. What I'm trying to get is the logged in user information without having any additional log in.

Comment: You can try register your app then get admin consent which will give you a token which assign to your app and use that token to call graph. You can review [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).